# ICursor is null when reading contacts Xamarin Android (Release)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Getting contacts from xamarin android is pretty straightforward and I've been using a `LoaderManager` / `CursorLoader` to implement it rather that the `Xamarin.Contacts` `Addressbook` which is slow for 100+ contacts or more.

So my question is that on the `DEBUG` build all contacts will just returns fine but when I build it to `RELEASE` and casting the `data` to `ICursor` it will just returns `null`.

[image]

So I logged the possible causes and turns out it does not have the `ICursor` interface implementation when `RELEASED`.

[image]

Any info would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than casting a `ICursor cursor = data as ICursor` it must be casted as `ICursor cursor = data.JavaCast<ICursor>();`